# Creating a long hex string results in an Out of Memory exception

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file, hex

I'm trying to process large concatenated files and split them back into individual files. For anyone who wants to know, `searchString` contains the magic numbers that make up the file headers and is used to tell where each file begins.

This line

```
string dataString = String.Concat(dataByte.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
```

...results in a:

> Out of Memory exception

I have seen a few different ways that large files can be processed, but none of those approaches seem to handle the data the way I need this program to. Is there any way to correct the `Out of Memory exception` without changing anything inside the foreach loop?

```
byte[] dataByte = File.ReadAllBytes(pathString);

string dataString = String.Concat(dataByte.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));

string[] LineArray = Regex.Split(dataString, searchString);

foreach (string LineResult in LineArray)

{

     //The string processing operations go here.
     //The individual files are created from the output.

}
```

Comment: What if you process chunks not the file entirely?

Comment: How big the main file?

Comment: _"I'm trying to process large concatenated files"_ - Methods like `File.ReadAllBytes` are evil when you know the file is going to be large sadly.  Instead you should look to process smaller blocks as suggested by zerkms

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you tried using StringBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are an awful way to handle large quantities of data, since they are immutable, the code as you have it will create a ton of copies of each as it processes each.

Try to use everything as bytes until you cannot, and deal in chunks as opposed to all at one time.

For example, read bytes from the file until you see the magic bytes (that you created from the magic string) the process that, save it, then continue on. Arrays must be contiguous, so limit their size to avoid running out of large chunks of memory even though there is plenty available overall.

Comment: Every call to b.tostring creates a new string. FOR EVERY BYTE IN YOUR FILE! Id call that a lot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with processing files in chunks. Would it still work if the chunk only contained a portion of the magic bytes? I don't think it would. That's why I think I still need to process the entire file at once. After all, the magic bytes have to be intact in order to be identified. If the second line of code was removed and the last two were corrected to work with bytes instead of strings, do you think the program would work correctly?

Comment: I think you could simply have a 2 byte arrays of decent size, read into the first one search for magic bytes. If not found, move the bytes to the second array. Read in enough bytes to fill in the second.  Check the combined in case the magic bytes span the arrays. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: The inspiration from your answer helped a lot, Tim! I ended up switching to Java, but the solution I worked out would still apply in C# with a few changes.  I used a BufferedInputStream to read through the entire file. C#'s equivalent is BufferedStream, I think. The program stores the offset of each occurrence of the magic bytes in a list. It then goes back and refers to the list. From there, it copies each portion into new files.